# Reflect changes of same Vue Component to different routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a Filter tab component. That i used in different routes. Whenever click on any tab it is being active. After clicking one i want to make the same tab to be active in other routes also. How can i do so? Any article or suggestion will be really helpful.

[image]

Here's my filter tab component

```
<template>
  <div class="filter-container">
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      v-ripple
      :identifier="random()"
      :class="[`item i${item.id}`, { 'active': activeId == item.id }]"
      @click="scrollInto(item.id, $event)"
    >
      {{ item.label }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FilterTabs',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      activeId: this.items.length ? this.items[0].id : null,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    items(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.activeId = newValue[0].id;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    scrollInto(id, event) {
      this.activeId = id;
      setTimeout(() => {
        const identifier = event.target.attributes.identifier.value;
        document.querySelectorAll(`[identifier='${identifier}']`)[0].scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center',
        });

        // var selectors = document.querySelectorAll(`.i${id}`);

        // selectors.forEach((node) => {
        //   node.scrollIntoView({
        //     behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center',
        //   });
        // })
      }, 100);
      this.$emit('onTagChange', id);
    },
    random() {
      return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + '-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is `route2` another component? Seems like a good time to learn about Vuex ;)

Comment: You can try using `props` concept or can learn `Vuex` if both the components are the routes are in different components, but if they are in the same component then you can use the `data` to maintain a local state for the page.

Comment: Any other concepts without using vuex? Like one instance but multiple views for separate places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend Vuex as per previous comments. But since you are asking for other solutions. Here are some not so elegant approaches:

1. Global Event Bus - keep the active tab in a global EventBus state that will also  listen to changes, and emit changes. As this will not be destroyed between routes, you can get the event bus state on route change (component mount/create).
2. Use Portal-Vue to teleport filter tab component on demand to other views/routes keeping it's state. More: https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue
3. Keep active tab in url hash `https://example.com/#tab-1` or URLSearchParam `https://example.com/route1?tab=2`. And load param/hash on route change/component mount. The biggest downside to that is that you need to manually pass the hash or URL search param to every link.

Comment: Solved using Vuex. But portal view seems the exact component i needed.... Thanks.